# Why there is no "goldware" vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

We can use the words *copperware* and *silverware* to express the copper and silver products, but why is there no *goldware* to express the golden products?

Comment: I have checked and it appears that goldware fails to appear in many dictionaries. So now I have the same question. Why isn't it generally considered to be a word?

Comment: Actually, the number of Google hits on goldware and copperware are very similar, both around 300,000, while silverware hits number 17 million.  This is undoubtedly because silverware is a "thing," i.e. forks, spoons, knives and the like, and before stainless steel became available, was the most likely type of metal eating utensils.  Copperware is less of a "thing," since it's mostly pots and pans and the like, which for ages could also be cast iron...so it's not a general word for cooking vessels.  And goldware...who would use that, Donald Trump and Warren Buffett?  Also, it's "vocabulary."

Comment: Well someone uses it because if I search Google images it's there https://goo.gl/ZYBiub -- It may be  rare but  what does Donald Trump's butler request for special occasions?   I'm still surprised it's not  in dictionaries. As a check, I compared with  'gold-ware' and 'gold ware' and they weren't so common - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goldware%2Cgold-ware%2Cgold+ware&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoldware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgold%20-%20ware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgold%20ware%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm now wondering why it isn't "goldenware" - it sounds better, and compare with "earthenware". What's with the "-en" in golden?

Comment: Presumably those writing the dictionaries did not feel that "goldware" was a sufficiently common term to merit inclusion, while "silverware" and "copperware" are words that the average person might reasonably use.  Keep in mind that no dictionary carries every "word" in the English language, and most are consciously restricted to the most common words.  (And I doubt that many dictionaries use Google hits to gauge how common a word is.)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - "Generally considered to be a word"??  I doubt that that's the only criterion for inclusion in most dictionaries.

Comment: An assumption that has been made in these comments is that <metal>ware refers solely to kitchen equipment and dining utensils. Maybe that assumption is true -- I don't know. That leads to the question of how we distinguish objets  d'Art in various metals. If they are not 'ware', what are they?

Comment: Note that _silverware_ is a much more common word in American than British English. In Britain, we would use the word _silverware_ only for articles which actually are silver: the ordinary word for knives, forks, spoons is _cutlery_.

Comment: @ColinFine - Interesting. So in effect the AmE term refers to the appearance of the cutlery rather than the material it is made of. (?)  How is US plastic cutlery referred to? Is it called plastic silverware (despite not being shiny or metallic in appearance)?

Comment: @JHCL   Don't pay a lot of money for a piece of jewelry described by the seller as "golden".  It isn't really gold.

Answer (score 3):

Gold is more commonly encountered in combination with ***'plate'***; while silver also appears in this formation. Note that this is not a reference to materials that are *'plated'* as in thinly coated, but in the sense that it is a gold or silver item with some utility and not bullion or (usually) coinage.  The OED references:

> plate ▪ I.plate, n.
>   (pleɪt)
>   Forms: 3– plate; also 5 plaate, 5–6 platt, playt(e, pla(y)the, 5–7 plaite, plaitt, 5–8 plat, plait, 6 (Sc.) pleit, plet.
>   [ME. plate, a. OF. plate (c 1175 in Littré) thin plate, lamina of metal, etc. (in form = Pr., Sp. plata, Pg. prata, It. piatta), in origin the fem. form of F. plat, plate:—late and med.L. plattus, -a, -um adj. ‘flat’: see plat a. (In Sp. and Pg., from the sense ‘plate or disk of metal’ (quasi *plata d'argento plate of silver, coin), plata, prata developed that of ‘silver, money’, in which sense it has superseded argento.) Senses 13 and 14 are orig. from OF., but were reinforced in 16th c. from Sp. plata. In sense 15, plate represents OF. vaisselle en plate, orig. vessels (dishes, plates, etc.) of a single piece of metal (not made up of pieces), **particularly of silver or gold**, mod.F. vaisselle plate = (silver) plate. Branch III might be considered a distinct word; it represents OF. plat (14th c. in Littré) ‘a platter or great dish; also, a dish of meat’ (Cotgr.) = It. piatto, ‘a platter, a dish, a charger, a plate’; also ‘a messe or dish of meat’ (Florio), med.L. plat(t)um, in origin the masc. or neuter form of the same adj. (quasi-late L. *vas plattum flat vessel). But in Eng. it has run together with the senses from OF. plate, and is more or less associated with senses 15, 17. From the OF. plate, or its Romanic equivalent, came also MLG., MDu., LG. plāte, Du. plaat, MHG. plate, blate, Ger. platte a plate.]
>
> II. A thin piece of silver or gold; silver or gold utensils.
>
> 15. a. Precious metal; bullion: from 16th c. usually silver, after Sp. plata. Now only Hist.
>       *a 1400–50 Alexander 3673 All pargeste of plate, as pure as þe noble. c 1430 [see prec. sense]. 1559 Morwyng Evonym. 78 Some vse..a pipe of white plate or other metall, very longe, writhen into many boughtes and tourninges. 1621 G. Sandys Ovid's Met. ii. (1626) 219 Assumed viands straight Betweene his greedie teeth conuert to plate. 1671 tr. Palafox's Conq. China xxxii. 567 The buttons are ordinary of Plate, either Silver or Gold. 1702 Luttrell Brief Rel. (1857) V. 185 The Spanish governours..are resolved not to suffer any plate to be brought thence to Europe. 1740 tr. Barba's Metals, Mines & Min. 59 And find Abundance of Plate in them, which can be attributed to nothing but to the perpetual Generation of Silver.*
> 16. collect. sing. Utensils for table and domestic use, ornaments, etc.: a. originally of silver or gold.
>       *c 1400 Destr. Troy 9504 Bassons full brode, & other bright vessell; Pesis of plates plentius mekyll. 1454 Rolls of Parlt. V. 255/2 To ley in plege all my grete Jowellys, and the most partie of my Plate. 1489 Caxton Faytes of A. i. xxi. 67 A grete quantyte of plate bothe of golde and of syluere. 1530 Palsgr. 255/2 Plate sylver vessel, uaysselle dargent. 1583 Rates of Customs D vij b, Plate gilt the vnce vs. Plate parcel gilt y⊇ vnce iiijs. vid. Plate white the vnce iiijs. 1600 Holland Livy xxxiv. lii. 882 Many vessels of plate of all sorts, and most engrauen. 1662 Pepys Diary 27 Apr., A salt-cellar of silver,..one of the neatest pieces of plate that ever I saw. 1711 Addison Spect. No. 15 ⁋4 Whether they keep their Coach and six, or eat in Plate. 1773 Lond. Chron. 7 Sept. 248/3 Sacramental plate. 1846 Landor Imag. Conv., Southey & Landor Wks. 1853 II. 73/1 The rich cupboards of embossed plate. 1885 Law Times LXXIX. 175/1 A service of plate bequeathed by a baronet to devolve with his baronetcy.*

Exactly why *'plate'* is used to refer to gold and silver utility products, while *'-ware'* is also used for silver but almost never for gold is a mystery.  The root meaning of *'-ware'*  is an object of trade or manufacture, as the OED has it:

> ▪ III.ware, n.3
>   (wɛə(r))
>   Forms: 1 waru, 4–6 war, (4 quare, whare), 5–6 warre, 6 waar; 5–6 Sc. and north. wayr(e, 6 wayere, 6–7 wair(e; 2– ware.
>   [OE. waru fem. = OFris. were, MLG., MDu. ware (Du. waar), ON. vara (Sw. vara, Da. vare). MHG. ware, war, G. ware (earlier waare) are from MLG. or MDu.
>   Prob. the same word as ware n.2 used in the concrete sense ‘object of care’.]
>   1. A collective term for: Articles of merchandise or manufacture; the things which a merchant, tradesman, or pedlar, has to sell; goods, commodities. a. collect. sing.
>   *c 1000 ælfric Hom. I. 246 Hi ða wurpon heora waru oforbord. a 1100 Voc. in Wr.-Wülcker 311/35 Merx, waru. c 1205 Lay. 11356 Chæpmen bunden heore ware. a 1300 Cursor M. 4180 Wit camels þat gret birþin bar, O spice and of oþer ware. c 1386 Chaucer Wife's Prol. 522 Greet prees at market maketh deere ware. 1484 Caxton Fables of Alfonce i, The merchaunt of Baldak came in to egypte for to chepe & bye somme ware or marchaundyse. 1542–3 Act 34 & 35 Hen. VIII, c. 10 §2 Putting the same naughtie ware to sale secretly. 1614 Overbury Wife etc. (1638) 126 Its now like Ware miss-laid in a Pedlers pack; a ha 's it but knowes not where it is. 1634 Sir T. Herbert Trav. 61 The windowes of painted glasse (no common ware). 1697 Dryden Virg. Past. iv. 47 No Keel shall cut the Waves for foreign Ware. 1748 Smollett Rod. Rand. viii, He certainly intended to make free with the pedlar's ware. c 1820 [see pieman]. 1822 Scott Peveril xlii, I am always provided with ware which a gentleman may risk his life on. 1844 Kinglake Eothen xviii, The owners raised various objections to the display of their ware [sc. white slave-girls].*
>
> b. pl.
>   *c 1000 ælfric Hom. II. 120 Ða ᵹelamp hit æt sumum sæle..þæt Englisce cypmenn brohton heora ware to Romana-byriᵹ... Þaᵹeseah he betwux ðam warum cype-cnihtas ᵹesette. c 1400 Destr. Troy 1581 There were stallis by þe strete stondyng for peopull, Werkmen into won, and þaire wares shewe. 1487 Cely Papers (Camden) 165 He avysyth yow to bestowe yowre mony in grosse warys now betymys. 1567 Harman Caveat 62 Consideringe wyth hym selfe that wares woulde bee welcome where money wanted. 1622 Bacon Hen. VII, 188 With whom ventured also three small Shippes of London-Merchants, fraught with some grosse and sleight Wares, fit for Commerce with barbarous people. a 1625 Fletcher Woman's Prize v. i, Give 'em as little light As Drapers doe their wares. 1698 Acts Massachusetts (1724) 117 Leather..wrought into Shoes, Boots, or other Wares. 1776 Adam Smith W.N. iv. ii. II. 52 A capricious man of fashion might sometimes prefer foreign wares, merely because they were foreign, to cheaper and better goods of the same kind that were made at home. 1834 James J. Marston Hall I. xii. 159, I perceived..a man in the dress of a pedlar, with his box of wares laid down by his side. 1913 G. Edmundson Ch. Rome 1st C. v. 123 A fire broke out..amidst shops containing inflammable wares.*

Given that *'-ware'* includes a sense of 'guarded items', hence valuable items it is strange that gold is not included.  On the other hand, as the use of *'-ware'* evolved it may have had too much a suggestion of commerce and utility, and the owners of *'plate'* may have preferred to retain their more archaic (and exclusive) terminology.

*'Plate'* is often encountered in references to crime, the wealth of the aristocracy, and of the Church.  In the latter case it would refer to the chalices and other elements of the alter and service, as in:

[image]

From 'Religion in Society, Or, the Solution of Great Problems' by Antoine Martinet, 1850.  Note the distinction between the *'plate'* (utility items) and *'ornaments'* in the text.

Gold utility items are also described in combination with the word ***'wrought'***, meaning worked or manufactured.  We would be more familiar nowadays with *'wrought iron'* than *'wrought gold'*, but it has long usage as the OED describes:

> wrought ▪ I. wrought, n.Obs.rare
>   In 3 wrohte, 4 w(h)rouhte.
>   [Early ME. var. of wruhte (OE. wryhta), wright n.1]
>   = wright n.1 1, 1 b.
>   c 1275 Lay. 16969 Wrohtes, þat mid axe couþen weorche. Ibid. 21134 Wigar þe wittye wrohte. a 1333 W. Herebert in Relig. Lyrics 14th C. (1924) 22 Holy wrouhte of sterres bryht. Ibid. 27 Louerd god almyhti, Whrouhte of alle þinge.
>   ▪ II.wrought, ppl. a.
>   (rɔːt)
>   Forms: 3–4 wroȝt, 5–6 wroght, 5– wrought (6 arch. wroughten), 5 wrout, 7 wrote.
>   [ME. wroȝt, var. worht, pa. pple. of wirchen, wurchen: see work v.]
>   Worked into shape (or condition).
>   Freq. as the second element of combs., as fine-, finely-, **gold-**, hammer-, hand-, hard-, high-, highly-, machine-, thick-, thin-, well-wrought: see these words, and cf. in-, for-, over-, unwrought ppl. adjs.
>   I. 1. a. Created; shaped, moulded. Obs.
>   *c 1250 Gen. & Ex. 2606 Teremuth..bad it ben to hire broȝt, And saȝ ðis child wol faire wroȝt. c 1400 [see well-wrought ppl. a. 1]. 1434 Misyn Mending Life 126 God truly is infinit of gretnes,..of all wroght kyndes vnconsauyd.*
>
> 4. a. Of metals: Beaten out or shaped with the hammer or other tools.
>      *1535 Coverdale Ps. xliv. 13 Hir clothinge is of wrought golde. 1585 Higins Junius' Nomencl. 403/1 Argentum factum,..wrought siluer, as plate, coyne, &c. 1687 Miége Gt. Fr. Dict. ii. s.v. Ouvré, Wrought Silver,..wrought Brass. 1696–7 Act 8–9 William III, c. 34 §1 Evrey Hundred weight of Tin wrought commonly called Pewter. 1717 Berkeley Jrnl. Tour Italy Wks. 1871 IV. 555 Gold and silver, wrought and unwrought, found along the side of the little sea. 1819 Shelley Fragm., Tale Untold 3 Empty cups of wrought and daedal gold. 1885 Mag. Art Sept. 459/1 A circular plate of thin wrought bronze. 1893 Outing XXII. 111/1 A wrought-gold bracelet.*

Note, though, that *'wrought gold'* does not preclude ornaments or jewellery, or even gold thread.  ***'Plate'*** on the other hand is solidly utilitarian, even if it is only to be handled by Trumps and Bishops in our modern world.